# Meaning of "a dollar or more"

Tags: meaning, difference

1. It costs a dollar or more.
2. It costs a dollar, or it costs more than a dollar.

Do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're the same.

"It costs a dollar or more" means exactly one dollar, or an amount more than one dollar. Amount ≥ $1.

"It costs more than a dollar" means amount > $1, but not equal.

Bear in mind that someone may be approximating. If you asked someone the price of a product and he said, "a dollar", I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually 99 cents or $1.05.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they convey the same sense. However, the former is better as the repetition of "costs" in the latter is unnecessary.

Comment: It's not just the repeated word; the way #2 is written might be confusing to a reader. Outside of the context of explaining #1, it's not a very good way to describe the price of something.